# Java7 WatcheService events not receiving

Tags: java, scala, akka, watchservice

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid with this WatchService but I can't get my head around it, so maybe someone can shed some light here..

I wrote the simplest scala wrapper around java's watchService, in order to be called back with events:

```
object Watcher {
  def start(path: Path)(listener: ((String,Path)) => Unit) {
    val watchService = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService
    path.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE)

    var loop = true

    future {
      while(loop) {
        println("take...")
        for {
          key <- Try(watchService.take) 
          ev <- key.pollEvents
        } {
          println(ev.kind.name)
          listener((ev.kind.name, ev.context.asInstanceOf[Path]))
          if (!key.reset) loop = false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if I run this by hand in simple a "main" program, it runs exactly as it should: A file creation gives me both an ENTRY_CREATE and ENTRY_MODIFY events in the same loop iteration (why not), then a modification gives me another ENTRY_MODIFY, finally a delete gives me an ENTRY_DELETE.

So far so good.

Now I try to wrap this in akka so that events are sent to an actor and.. my watchService seems to just be stuck on take and doesn't come out of there!

```
class WatcherActor extends Actor {
  import Watcher._
  def receive = {
    case path: String =>
      val to = sender
      start(Paths.get(path)) { evt =>
        println(s"$evt => $to")
        to ! evt
      }
  }
}
```

I'm not blaming anyone else but myself, but this is driving me nuts :)

The code is very small, but instead of copying everything here, I've posted the code on github (just easier to reproduce):
https://github.com/joune/watcher

Anyone wants to give me a hand here?

PS: I'm on Linux 3.11.6-200.fc19.x86_64

Comment: note: if I touch files on the command line while running the akka test, I see the events, so it's not so much a problem with akka as with my way of testing

Comment: I looked at your examples. Akka example work fine except that `watchService` should start before file actually will created. It should be synchronized or at least add delay after you are sending message to `WatcherActor`.

Comment: d'oh!! I knew this was going to hurt! I did overlook the fact that this first 'tell' call is asynchronous! thanks aim! I can just add an "expectNoMsg" before creating the file and it works..

Comment: well, now that I already made a fool of myself, I'd like to get to the bottom of this. My tests are still very unstable: every once in a while, either (or both) test fails because I get an extra (third) MODIFY event, when I'm expecting a DELETE (expected (ENTRY_DELETE,file2-5811774905980517765), found (ENTRY_MODIFY,file2-5811774905980517765)). Nothing to do with akka this time, probably more with my usage of the test files... (i've updated the github)

Comment: Yep. I got the same. But modify and delete events comming in the same `WatchKey`. It seems that it platform specific thing (who knows what exactly going on under the hood?). Maybe will be better take last one from `pollEvents`. But in this case you can lost some useful data...